# How to get API call function that has multiple print statements to display in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, output

I've got a Python script that checks an API for train data using requests and prints out relevant information based on information stored in dictionaries. This works fine in the console, but I'd like for it to be accessible online, for this I've been recommend to use Flask.

However, I can't get around using the Flask's function/returns in the routes to get the same output as I get in the console. I've gotten as far as getting the the requests module imported, but this throws up a HTTPError 400 when I use my actual code.

How would I go about getting the console output printed out into a page? Here is my current code:

```
import requests
import re
from darwin_token import DARWIN_KEY

jsonToken = DARWIN_KEY

train_station = {'work_station': 'whs', 'home_station': 'tth', 'connect_station': 'ecr'}
user_time = {'morning_time': ['0821', '0853'], 'evening_time': ['1733'], 'connect_time': ['0834', '0843']}


def darwinChecker(departure_station, arrival_station, user_time):
    response = requests.get("https://huxley.apphb.com/all/" + str(departure_station) + "/to/" + str(arrival_station) + "/" + str(user_time), params={"accessToken": jsonToken})
    response.raise_for_status()    # this makes an error if something failed
    data1 = response.json()
train_service = data1["trainServices"]
print('Departure Station: ' + str(data1['crs']))
print('Arrival Station: ' + str(data1['filtercrs']))
print('-' * 40)
try:
    found_service = 0  # keeps track of services so note is generated if service not in user_time
    for index, service in enumerate(train_service):  # enumerate adds index value to train_service list
        if service['sta'].replace(':', '') in user_time:  # replaces sta time with values in user_time
            found_service += 1  # increments for each service in user_time
            print('Service RSID: ' + str(train_service[index]['rsid']))
            print('Scheduled arrival time: ' + str(train_service[index]['sta']))
            print('Scheduled departure time: ' + str(train_service[index]['std']))
            print('Status: ' + str(train_service[index]['eta']))
            print('-' * 40)
            if service['eta'] == 'Cancelled':
                print('The ' + str(train_service[index]['sta']) + ' service is cancelled.')
                print('Previous train departure time: ' + str(train_service[index - 1]['sta']))
                print('Previous train status: ' + str(train_service[index - 1]['eta']))
    if found_service == 0:  # if no service is found
        print('The services currently available are not specified in user_time.')
except TypeError:
    print('There is no train service data')
try:
    NRCCRegex = re.compile('^(.*?)[\.!\?](?:\s|$)')  # regex pulls all characters until hitting a . or ! or ?
    myline = NRCCRegex.search(data1['nrccMessages'][0]['value'])  # regex searches through nrccMessages
    print('\nNRCC Messages: ' + myline.group(1) + '\n')  # prints parsed NRCC message
except (TypeError, AttributeError) as error:  # tuple catches multiple errors, AttributeError for None value
    print('\nThere is no NRCC data currently available\n')

print('Morning Journey'.center(50, '='))

darwinChecker(train_station['home_station'], train_station['connect_station'], user_time['morning_time'])
```

The only thing I can think of is that I'd have to split each print statement in a function and a corresponding return?

Any help/clarification would be much appreciated!

Comment: I would recommend going through the basic flask tutorial in the documentation.  It will show you how to handle routes, templates, and importing other scripts to run. These things will allow you to build what you want.  Once you've completed it and tried on your own you might be able to form a more specific question.

Comment: Alright, good shout, I'll actually go through the whole tutorial and see what I can figure out!